# How to forward auto-generated mails?

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding, confluence, yahoo-mail

I'm using Confluence and I want to send every Confluence user the daily notifications of the changes on it without making them to suscribe that notifications manually. All my Confluence users are members of a Yahoo group, so I want to send that message to the group automatically to make my Confluence users receive it.

My first idea was to create a user in Confluence whose email address was the same as the Yahoo group, and suscribe only that user to the notifications, so the mail will be received by all the members of the group (which are the same as Confluence users). I tried it but Confluence does not send the mail to the Yahoo account (I don't know why). The outgoing mail server is well-configured, because I receive the notifications in my email account (I'm suscribed manually to the notifications).

I supposed that the problem was with Yahoo mail or maybe with Yahoo Groups, so I decided to use an intermediate email account (I could solve it with Google Grous, but I need to avoid managing another group), and I used Gmail. I configured the forwarding, but it does not work with autogenerated mails, so I tried it with hotmail, but I have the same problem.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Please, does anybody know why auto generated mails aren't sent? Or, if not, does anybody know any email account which does send that mails?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not forward autogenerated mails, but if you use a mail client like Thunderbird or Outlook, the mails are forwarded.